# Google Maps and Navigation

Tags: android, google-maps

Is Google Maps and Google Navigation the same package?

I want to check if Google Navigation is installed before launching this intent

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
Uri.parse("google.navigation:ll="+toPosition.latitude+","+ toPosition.longitude));
startActivity(intent);
```

And i use this method to check if its installed

```
public boolean isGoogleNavInstalled()
    {
        try
        {
            ApplicationInfo info =  getActivity().getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo("google.navigation", 0 );
            return true;
        } 
        catch(PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

But this always returns FALSE. What is the exact name of the package for google navigation? If its the same as google maps, then it is ok to assume that any version of google maps, regarding the device and API level, comes with navigation ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is Google Maps and Google Navigation the same package?

Yes.

> I want to check if Google Navigation is installed before launching this intent

More relevant to the user would be to see if the `Intent` resolves to anything, such as via `resolveActivity()` on `PackageManager`. If the user wishes to use some other app to handle that request, that is the user's prerogative.

> But this always returns FALSE

That's because you are passing a package name that does not exist on your device.

> What is tha exact name of the package for google navigation?

Google Navigation does not exist as an independent package. It is part of Google Maps.

> If its the same as google maps, then it is ok to assume that any version of google maps, regarding the device and API level, comes with navigation ?

I certainly would not assume that, as there may be distribution limitations on the navigation portion, due to local laws, license terms with upstream data providers, etc.

That's why it is far more relevant to the user for you to see if your desired `Intent` resolves to something, using `queryIntentActivities()` or `resolveActivity()` on `PackageManager`.. Just because *you* may want to use Google Navigation does not mean that *everyone* wants to use Google Navigation.

Note that your `Intent` is relying upon an undocumented `Uri` structure anyway, and so there is no assurance that even Google Maps will honor it.

Comment: excellent answer! Thank you very much. I'm not so sure what to do then for navigation. Is there a standard way of doing this?

Comment: @klifa: There is no official `Intent` structure that will lead the user to navigation. Hence, your use of `google.navigation:` is about as good as it will get. My points are that you should worry about whether your `Intent` resolves rather than if such-and-so app is installed, and don't complain if you run into compatibility issues when using an undocumented `Uri` like this. :-)

Comment: Hi @CommonsWare can I implement Google navigation grammatically?

Comment: @Dipu: I have no idea what you mean by that. Perhaps consider asking a fresh Stack Overflow question, where you explain completely and precisely what you mean.

Answer (score 2):

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
    Uri.parse("google.navigation:q=" + point.getLat() + "," + point.getLon()));
    if(!canHandleIntent(mActivity, intent)) {
         intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
         intent.setData(Uri.parse("market://detailsid=com.google.android.apps.maps"));
    }
    startActivity(intent);

public boolean canHandleIntent(Context context, Intent intent){
     PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
     List activities = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(
                intent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
        return !(activities == null || activities.size() == 0);
}
```

if the Intent resolves to anything start appropriate app with the Intent, else open Google Play on page of Google Maps.